# std::unordered_map::find using a type different than the Key type?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have an `unordered_map` that uses a string-type as a key:

```
std::unordered_map<string, value> map;
```

A `std::hash` specialization is provided for `string`, as well as a 
suitable `operator==`.

Now I also have a "string view" class, which is a weak pointer into an existing string, avoiding heap allocations:

```
class string_view {
    string *data;
    size_t begin, len;
    // ...
};
```

Now I'd like to be able to check if a key exists in the map using a `string_view` object. Unfortunately,  `std::unordered_map::find` takes a `Key` argument, not a generic `T` argument.

(Sure, I can "promote" one to a `string`, but that causes an allocation I'd like to avoid.)

What I would've liked instead was something like

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class unordered_map
{
    template<class T> iterator find(const T &t);
};
```

which would require `operator==(T, Key)` and `std::hash<T>()` to be suitably defined, and would return an iterator to a matching value.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Can you change your program to use a custom `string` class that manages its own string/heap allocations?

Comment: While I am thinking on the answer, just a small note - your `string_view` class is usually called `string_ref`

Comment: why not supply a casting operator to a `std::string` reference in your `string_view` that refers to `data`?  `operator std::string&() { return *data; }`  Then there is no allocation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Presumably that `string_view` represents a portion of the string, not the full thing.

Comment: There's no heterogeneous lookup for unordered associative containers. There are implementations in which `hash<int>` and `hash<short>` return different results for the same value.

Comment: @T.C.  ok, I see that there is a problem if that represents the partial string and not the full string.

Comment: @Dai: heh, unfortunately no, I can't.

Comment: @T.C.: right, but in this case I can control `hash` and provide it in such a way that it honors the hashing equality. IOW `string s; string_view sv; (s == sv) → hash(s) == hash(sv)`. (Pretty easy given they're strings)

Comment: How about a third type for the key that can contain either a string or a `string_view`?

Comment: @MarkRansom: yes, I thought of such a "variant type". However it doesn't look as a clean solution (like, should this type have the entire `string` API available? By reimplementing it? Should it inherit `string`?)

Comment: It wouldn't take much of an API, just copy constructors for `string_view` and `std::string`, `operator==` and hashing. And perhaps a conversion back to `std::string` if you want to use the key type for anything but lookups.

Comment: For awareness: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r2.html has been merged into C++2a.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[P0919R2 Heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r2.html) has been merged in the C++2a's working draft!

The abstract seems a perfect match w.r.t. my original question :-)

> ## Abstract
>
> This proposal adds heterogeneous lookup support to the unordered associative containers in the C++ Standard Library. As a result, a creation of a temporary key object is not needed when different (but compatible) type is provided as a key to the member function. This also makes unordered and regular associative container interfaces and functionality more compatible with each other.
>
> With the changes proposed by this paper the following code will work without any additional performance hits:
>
> ```
> template<typename Key, typename Value>
> using h_str_umap = std::unordered_map<Key, Value, string_hash>;
> h_str_umap<std::string, int> map = /* ... */;
> map.find("This does not create a temporary std::string object :-)"sv);
> ```

Full example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>
 
using namespace std::literals;
 
struct string_hash
{
    using hash_type = std::hash<std::string_view>;
    using is_transparent = void;
 
    std::size_t operator()(const char* str) const        { return hash_type{}(str); }
    std::size_t operator()(std::string_view str) const   { return hash_type{}(str); }
    std::size_t operator()(std::string const& str) const { return hash_type{}(str); }
};
 
int main()
{
    // simple comparison demo
    std::unordered_map<int,char> example = {{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}};
 
    if (auto search = example.find(2); search != example.end())
        std::cout << "Found " << search->first << " " << search->second << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
 
    // C++20 demo: Heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers (transparent hashing)
    std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t, string_hash, std::equal_to<>> map{{"one"s, 1}};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << (map.find("one")   != map.end()) << '\n'
        << (map.find("one"s)  != map.end()) << '\n'
        << (map.find("one"sv) != map.end()) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned above, C++14 does not provide heterogeneous lookup for `std::unordered_map` (unlike `std::map`). You can use Boost.MultiIndex to define a fairly close substitute for `std::unordered_map` that allows you to look up `string_view`s without allocating temporary `std::string`s:

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d927eeb60330863)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct string_view
{
  std::string *data;
  std::size_t begin,len;
};

template<typename T,typename Q>
struct mutable_pair
{
  T         first;
  mutable Q second;
};

struct string_view_hash
{
  std::size_t operator()(const string_view& v)const
  {
     return boost::hash_range(
       v.data->begin()+v.begin,v.data->begin()+v.begin+v.len);
  }
  std::size_t operator()(const std::string& s)const
  {
     return boost::hash_range(s.begin(),s.end());
  }
};

struct string_view_equal_to
{
  std::size_t operator()(const std::string& s1,const std::string& s2)const
  {
     return s1==s2;
  }
  std::size_t operator()(const std::string& s1,const string_view& v2)const
  {
     return s1.size()==v2.len&&
            std::equal(
              s1.begin(),s1.end(),
              v2.data->begin()+v2.begin);
  }
  std::size_t operator()(const string_view& v1,const std::string& s2)const
  {
     return v1.len==s2.size()&&
            std::equal(
              v1.data->begin()+v1.begin,v1.data->begin()+v1.begin+v1.len,
              s2.begin());
  }
};

template<typename Q>
using unordered_string_map=multi_index_container<
  mutable_pair<std::string,Q>,
  indexed_by<
    hashed_unique<
      member<
        mutable_pair<std::string,Q>,
        std::string,
        &mutable_pair<std::string,Q>::first
      >,
      string_view_hash,
      string_view_equal_to
    >
  >
>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unordered_string_map<int> m={{"hello",0},{"boost",1},{"bye",2}};

  std::string str="helloboost";
  auto it=m.find(string_view{&str,5,5});
  std::cout<<it->first<<","<<it->second<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
boost,1
```

Comment: thank you for precising `unlike map` because that's why I'm here. I thought that issue was long solved. And then here I am faced with build issues with `unordered` only to see it was half solved. thanks

Answer (score 9):

I faced an equal problem.

We need two structs:

```cpp
struct string_equal {
    using is_transparent = std::true_type ;

    bool operator()(std::string_view l, std::string_view r) const noexcept
    {
        return l == r;
    }
};


struct string_hash {
    using is_transparent = std::true_type ;

    auto operator()(std::string_view str) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>()(str);
    }
};
```

For unordered_map:

```cpp
template <typename Value>
using string_unorderd_map = std::unordered_map<std::string, Value, string_hash, string_equal>;
```

For unordered_set:

```cpp
using string_unorderd_set = std::unordered_set<std::string, string_hash, string_equal>;
```

Now using string_view is possible.

Comment: `string_unorderd_map.find(string_view)` doesn't work.

Comment: @Spongman, 
Example: https://godbolt.org/z/8c8nYb
But my example works only on compiler supporting cpp20 and this feature (at the current moment this is only msvc)

Comment: The question explicitly tagged c++11.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like only as recently as C++14 did even the basic `map` get such a templated find for `is_transparent` types in the comparison. Most likely the correct implementation for hashed containers was not immediately evident.

As far as I can see your two options are:

- Just do the allocation and profile to see if maybe it's not actually a problem.
- Take a look at `boost::multi_index` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) and have both `string` and `string_view` indexes into the container.

Comment: Doesn't boost::multi_index actually maintain two indices? That seems like it would be a lot more overhead than allocating and destroying a new string, although I agree with OP that the allocation is pointless.

Comment: Please see my answer on using Boost.MultiIndex for solving this: it does not use but one index, so the memory overhead is the same as with `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has drawbacks, which may or may not make it unviable for your context.

You can make a wrapper class:

```
struct str_wrapper {
  const char* start, end;
};
```

And change your map to use str_wrapper as its key. You'd have to add 2 constructors to str_wrapper, one for std::string and one for your string_view. The major decision is whether to make these constructors perform deep or shallow copies.

For example, if you use std::string only for inserts and str_view only for lookups, you'd make the std::string constructor deep and the str_view one shallow (this can be enforced at compile time if you use a custom wrapper around unordered_map). If you care to avoid memory leaks on the deep copy you would need additional fields to support proper destruction.

If your usage is more varied, (looking up std::string's or inserting by str_view), there will be drawbacks, which again, might make the approach too distasteful so as to be unviable. It depends on your intended usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to split the lookup and the data management by using multiple containters:

```
std::unordered_map<string_view, value> map;
std::vector<unique_ptr<const char[]>> mapKeyStore;
```

Lookups are done using `string_view`s without the need of allocations.
Whenever a new key is inserted we need to add a real string allocation first:

```
mapKeyStore.push_back(conv(str)); // str can be string_view, char*, string... as long as it converts to unique_ptr<const char[]> or whatever type
map.emplace(mapKeyStore.back().get(), value)
```

It would be much more intuitive to use `std::string` in the `mapKeyStore`. However, using `std::string` does not guarantee unchanging string memory (e.g. if the vector resizes). With the `unique_ptr` this is enforced. However, we need some special conversion/allocation routine, called `conv` in the example. If you have a custom string container which guarantees data consistency under moves (and forces the vector to use moves), then you can use it here.

**The drawback**

The disadvantage of the above method is that handling deletions is non-trivial and expensive if done naive. If the map is only created once or only growing this is a non-issue and the above pattern works quite well.

**Running example**

The below example includes a naive deletion of one key.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using PayLoad = int;

unique_ptr<const char[]> conv(string_view str) {
    unique_ptr<char[]> p (new char [str.size()+1]);
    memcpy(p.get(), str.data(), str.size()+1);
    return move(p);
}

int main() {
    unordered_map<string_view, PayLoad> map;
    vector<unique_ptr<const char[]>> mapKeyStore;
    // Add multiple values
    mapKeyStore.push_back(conv("a"));
    map.emplace(mapKeyStore.back().get(), 3);
    mapKeyStore.push_back(conv("b"));
    map.emplace(mapKeyStore.back().get(), 1);
    mapKeyStore.push_back(conv("c"));
    map.emplace(mapKeyStore.back().get(), 4);
    // Search all keys
    cout << map.find("a")->second;
    cout << map.find("b")->second;
    cout << map.find("c")->second;
    // Delete the "a" key
    map.erase("a");
    mapKeyStore.erase(remove_if(mapKeyStore.begin(), mapKeyStore.end(),
        [](const auto& a){ return strcmp(a.get(), "a") == 0; }),
        mapKeyStore.end());
    // Test if verything is OK.
    cout << '\n';
    for(auto it : map)
        cout << it.first << ": " << it.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the two containers can be put into a wrapper which handles the insertion and deletion for its own.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just present one variation I found on github, it involves defining a new map class that wraps the std.
Redefining some key API to intercept the adaptors we want, and use a static string to copy the key.
It's not necessary a good solution, but it's interesting to know it exists for people who deems it enough.

original:
https://gist.github.com/facontidavide/95f20c28df8ec91729f9d8ab01e7d2df

code gist:

```
template <typename Value>
class StringMap: public std::unordered_map<std::string, Value>
{
public:
    typename std::unordered_map<string,Value>::iterator find(const nonstd::string_view& v )
    {
        tmp_.reserve(  v.size() );
        tmp_.assign( v.data(), v.size() );
        return std::unordered_map<string, Value>::find(tmp_);
    }

    typename std::unordered_map<std::string,Value>::iterator find(const std::string& v )
    {
        return std::unordered_map<std::string, Value>::find(v);
    }

    typename std::unordered_map<std::string,Value>::iterator find(const char* v )
    {
        tmp_.assign(v);
        return std::unordered_map<std::string, Value>::find(v);
    }

private:
    thread_local static std::string tmp_;
};
```

credits:
[Davide Faconti](https://gist.github.com/facontidavide)

Comment: As for me it looks not thread safe. `Find` function may be interrupted in the middle by OS and another thread may be scheduled in the same thread executing the same code and using the same std::string buffer.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry for answering this very old question, but it still comes up in search engine results...
In this case your unordered_map is using the string type as its key, the find method is looking for a reference to a string which will not generate an allocation. Your string_view class stores a pointer to a string. Therefore your string_view class can dereference the pointer into a ref of the type needed for your map without causing an allocation. The method would look like this...

```
string &string_view::getRef() const
{
    return *_ptr;
}
```

and to use the string_view with the map it would look like this

```
auto found=map.find(string_view_inst.getRef());
```

note that this will not work for the c++17 string_view class as it does not internally store a std::string object

ps.
Your string_view class is probably not great for cpu caches as it stores a pointer to a string allocated somewhere on the heap, and the string itself stores a pointer to the actual data located somewhere else on the heap. Every time you access your string_view it will result in a double dereference.

Comment: Look closely at OP's code. In addition to `string *`, OP's `string_view` also stores `size_t begin, len;`. They seem to want to use a substring of the pointed string (starting at `begin`, `len` characters long), not the entire string.

Comment: whoops, missed that.

Comment: not only that, but `string_view`s can wrap `static char const*` or even sub-ranges.

Answer (score -5):

You could allow your view to be implicitly convertible to a `std::string`:

```
class StringView {
    // ...
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return data->substr(begin, len);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: OP explained they do not want an allocation.