# Use of string_view for map lookup

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++14, string-view

The following code fails to build on recent compilers (g++-5.3, clang++-3.7).

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <experimental/string_view>

void f()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::experimental;
    map<string, int> m;
    string s = "foo";
    string_view sv(s);
    m.find(sv);
}
```

Error returned by clang :

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
    m.find(sv);
    ~~^~~~
```

But shouldn't `find` be able to use comparable types ? 
Cppreference mentions the following overload :

`template< class K > iterator find( const K& x );`

The same error happens with `boost::string_ref`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You need to specify a [*transparent comparator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/3953764) explicitly (like [`std::less<>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/comparisons#11)):

```
std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>> m;
//                         ~~~~~~~~~~^
```

`std::map<K,V>` defaults its comparator to [`std::less<K>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/comparisons#5) (i.e., a *non-transparent* one), and since ([[associative.reqmts]/p13](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#13)):

> The member function templates `find`, `count`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, and `equal_range` shall not participate in overload resolution unless the *qualified-id* `Compare::is_transparent` is valid and denotes a type (14.8.2).

the template member function `find` is not a viable candidate.

[Heterogeneous comparison lookup for associative containers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf) was added to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14). The original proposal risked breaking existing code. For example:

```
c.find(x);
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
key_type key = x;
c.find(key);
```

In particular, the conversion between `x` and `key_type` happens *only once*, and *before the actual call*.

Heterogenous lookup replaces this conversion in favour of a comparison between `key` and `x`. This may lead to a drop in performance in existing code (due to addtional conversion before each comparison) or even break compilation (if the comparison operator is a member function, it will not apply conversion for a left-hand side operand):

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    int i;

    A(int i) : i(i) {}
};

bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
    return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<A, std::less<>> s{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
    s.find(5);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c36a993e01180227)

To resolve this the new behaviour was made opt-in by adding the concept of transparent comparators as described in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/3953764).

Comment: How to do the same for unordered_map?

Comment: For unordered map you should use C++20: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530846/1266605