# C++: Find substring in a HashMap

Tags: c++, hashmap, substring, substr

I have a long string of urlParams, I would like to check if the keys in my string exist in the hashMap, one option would be to use `std::string.substr` to extract the keys from the source string and check if they are in the hashmap, however, I would like to avoid creating new objects.

Is there a way to check if my key in the hashmap by providing the source string, and the position of my key in that source?

I use a simple hashmap `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, but I can change it if you think it can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution to your problem is described here: [Use of string_view for map lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525777/use-of-string-view-for-map-lookup).

You want to create simply `string_view` (by source string and position, also by the length), and use it for lookup. No new objects created.