# Using string_view to search unordered_map<string, int>

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map, string-view

I need to extract all substring of a certain size from a given string and look-up each of them in a `std::unordered_map<string, int*>`. I tried to use the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525777/use-of-string-view-for-map-lookup) and used `std::less<>` as the comparator but the compiler (gcc 8.2) complains with the following error. I don't know if it even makes sense to fiddle with the comparator in case of an `unordered_map`.

```
/afs/software/gcc/8.2.0/lssc0-linux/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:195:21: error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type
    static_assert(__is_invocable<const _H1&, const _Key&>{}
c_counter.cpp: In function ‘void process(char*)’:
c_counter.cpp:158:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int*, std::less<void> >::find(std::string_view&)’ if (counts->find(k) != counts->end()) {
```

The code is:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int*, std::less<>> *counts = new std::unordered_map<std::string, int*, std::less<>> ;

// stuff

void prcoess(char* r) {
    std::string_view seq(r) ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= l - 1 - 15 ; i++) {
        string_view k = seq.substr(i, 15) ;
        if (counts->find(k) != counts->end()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The whole point of using `string_view` here is to avoid allocating memory and creating new strings for every substring, so is there any way that allows me to query the `unordered_map` without undermining the optimization?