# Does `std::map::at()` not support std::string_view?

Tags: c++

I use exceptions heavily in my code, so I prefer to use `at()` rather than `find()` to find an element, but I just found that `at()` seems not support `std::string_view`, for example:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>> map{
    {"one", 1},
    {"two", 2},
};

const char* c = "onetwothree";

int main() {
  std::string_view s(&c[3], 3);
  std::cout << map.find(s)->second << std::endl;
  std::cout << map.at(s) << std::endl; // will not compile
}
```

So can I use `at()` with `std::string_view`? Or in another word, can `at()` support heterogeneous lookup?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought a transparent comparator (i.e. `less<>`) was [required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35525806/7366707) for heterogeneous lookup? (the call to `find` won't compile otherwise, at least.)

Answer (score 2):

Since the C++14 standard the [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) function have templated overloads that support values *equivalent* to the keys.

The [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) function have no such overloads. The value passed to `at` *must* be the same type as the key (or implicitly convertible to the type of the key).

Comment: I don't think there's a strong reason for `at` to not support this. It doesn't have to insert anything into the map when the value isn't found (and so doens't have to try and convert a random object type into the key type), so transparent lookup can be made to work. `operator[]` is a no-starter on this, however. I reckon `at` doesn't support it only because it's supposed to be paired with `operator[]` in many ways.