# How to find by a key of type std::wstring_view in std::unordered_map<std::wstring, T>?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have

```
std::unordered_map<std::wstring, std::vector<unsigned>> map;
```

when I try

```
map.find("asdf"sv)
```

I get

```
error C2664: 'std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<_Kty,std::vector<unsigned int,std::allocator<unsigned int>>,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,false>>::find(const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>> &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::wstring_view' to 'const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>> &'
```

is it possible to make map.find() compile with std::wstring_view or at least to do the search without constructing std::wstring?

Comment: AFAIK not without constructing a `wstring`, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34597313/1870760

Comment: @SombreroChicken at least it is possible to make map.find() compile with std::wstring_view in C++ 20, see 3,4 at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called "heterogeneous lookup" (basically, the type of the map and the type you're trying to use to lookup are different types). In C++20, thanks to [P0919](https://wg21.link/p0919), we are going to get new overloads of [`unordered_map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) that will allow what you're trying to do to work.

Until then, the only relevant overload takes, specifically, a `Key const&`. And `basic_string`'s [constructor from `basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) is `explicit`  (see #10). So in C++17, you *have* to write:

```
map.find("asdf"s)
```

or

```
map.find(std::string("asdf"sv));
```